# Understanding the functionality of the "lsattr" command and its limitations on directories

Tags: filesystems

Why does `lsattr` only work on files? When I try to use it on a directory, it doesn't work, except for its contents. For files, the attributes are shown properly, but for directories, nothing is displayed.

For example:

```
$ sudo lsattr ~/.pcb
$
```

Can you please help me understand the limitations of this tool and its proper usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `lsattr` lists a directory’s contents; to see a directory’s attributes, you need to use the `-d` option:

```
lsattr -d ~/.pcb
```

Comment: I am not sure which OS that should be. in AIX (since ~v3.2.5, mid-nineties) "lsattr" lists the attributes of a device from the ODM. It won't work on neither files nor directories.

Comment: @bakunin given the context in the question, I’m assuming it’s [the `e2fsprogs` `lsattr`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lsattr.1.html).

Comment: Understood, thank you. Since the answer was accepted I am sure your assumption was correct too. Not using Linux I was not aware that it has an "lsattr" command too and much less that this command serves a completely different purpose.